# Word for two things that are opposite yet the same

Tags: synonyms, antonyms

Is there a word or short phrase that describes two contrasting ideas the ultimately end up the same? Like two ends of a spectrum that can wrap around? I'm using it to describe two foils for a character that ultimately end up being in the same boat.

This could also refer to examples such as Fascism and Communism, where the ends are very similar, but all other aspects are entirely different.

Comment: Are you thinking in a fated or predictable way?

Comment: @stevemarvell Maybe, but more cautionary. What word did you have in mind?

Comment: I would conjure a phrase using "inevitable" for predictability, "inescapable" if there might be an attempt to avoid the predicted future or "doomed to" if the future were considered negative.

Comment: maybe twin dangers?

Comment: I decided to use ends of a spectrum, hoping that they get the idea of a spectrum wrapping around.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *two foils for a character?* I would normally understand that usage to mean *two settings/backgrounds that help **illuminate** the [one and only] character*. Your usage seem to imply those *two foils* are in fact two *other* fictitious characters (who presumably serve the same purpose in the context of the story). Is that correct? If so, note that ["characters are two sides of the same coin"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22characters+are+two+sides+of+the+same+coin%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) does actually occur in Lit Crit contexts.

Comment: How about "a place where opposite extremes meet"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most common idiomatic usage for OP's context is

> ***two sides of the same coin***

The [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-two-sides-of-the-same-coin) definition is...

> *If two things are two sides of the same coin, they are very closely related although they seem different*

But personally I prefer this one from [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070517195924AATd3Uf)...

> *It means that the **same person or subject or idea** can be viewed two different ways.*
>    [emphasis mine]

---

In OP's *specific* example, [several hundred writers](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22walk%20into%20a%20job%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22Fascism%22%20%22Communism%22%20%22two%20sides%20of%20the%20same%20coin%22&tbm=bks) have in fact made the point that *Fascism and Communism are two sides of the same coin*. They mean *both are oppressive/totalitarian regimes*. Much the same idea is eloquently put by George Orwell in [the closing words of Animal Farm...](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/11670-the-creatures-outside-looked-from-pig-to-man-and-from)

> *“The creatures outside looked from pig to man, and from man to pig, and from pig to man again; but already it was impossible to say which was which.”*

Answer (score 4):

There is a "figure of speech" that may fit:

**[I'm damned if I do and damned if I don't.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I%27m+damned+if+I+do+and+damned+if+I+don%27t)**

There is **[Catch-22](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Catch-22)** also:

> (idiomatic) A difficult situation from which there is no escape because it involves mutually conflicting or dependent conditions.

Comment: I would up-vote but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

One phrase that expresses this:

> a rock and a hard place.

Or to make a general statement:

> All roads lead to ...

For instance, no matter how governments begin all roads lead to debt and dissipation.

Comment: I would up-vote but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score -1):

Juxtaposition
"noun : the fact of two things being seen or placed close together with contrasting effect."

Oxymoron
"noun : a figure of speech in which apparently contradictory terms appear in conjunction (e.g. faith unfaithful kept him falsely true )."